# Admob not working at AppStore

Tags: app-store, admob

I have implemented Ad mobs in my iPhone app. The app is receiving ads in simulator and device while debugging. but when i upload it to app store it is not receiving any.
I'm using this piece of code

```
-(void)showAds{
self.adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                origin:origin]autorelease];                     
self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"abcdef1234567890.";
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
[self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];

 GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

[self.adBanner loadRequest:request];
}
```

I dont know what mistake m I making ?? any help ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a period at the end of your adUnitID. Are you sure that should be there?

Comment: Do you have any error logs from your app? The code itself looks fine to me.